# Create Push Notification server for android without using GCM

Tags: android, push-notification

How can we create push notification service without using GCM to send the messages to a single android device.
I need not to use GCM because it is very slow and is a beta version.

Can any one please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Sathish

Comment: Just create a process and keep polling from your server. If your user does not worry about extra bandwidth and extra battery that your app will cost them. (I don't see a reason why you don't use GCM)

Comment: When I use GCM it is instantaneous.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Messaging is no in beta at all. :)

If you want to avoid using Google's service, better not to re-implement it. Try to use other frameworks, like Amazon's SNS for example:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Or

http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/PushFramework

Or something else.

Comment: Is OpenMobster down I cannot find it anymore?

Comment: Me too having the same problem as @confile

Answer (score 0):

You can install PSB ( http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/ ) and use the Java client API ( https://github.com/rpgmaker/PServiceBus-Java-Client ) to communicate between your android devices.

When creating application using the Java Client API. You can create a message such as.

```
public class Notification {
   public int Id;
   public String Message;
}
```

And when subscribing to the message on your android application, you simply apply a filter upon subscribing.

e.x

```
PSBClient.Subscribe(Notification.class, new Action<Notification>() {
   public void execute(Notification msg){
      //Do something with message
   }
}, "Id = UniqueAndroidID");
```

When Publishing the message to a particular device, you simply do the following:

```
Notification message = new Notification();
message.Id = 10003432;//Unique Android ID
message.Message = "Hello Android Device";
PSBClient.publish(message);
```